# React native state is not updating UI elements

Tags: typescript, react-native, state

im trying to fill up my view with elements. I am trying to use SetEvents to make the UI update, however it is not working.

My getEventsInCity returns standardResponse, .data of this is of type IEvent[]

My state

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState<IEvent[]>([testEvent,testEvent,testEvent])
```

My function

```
async function testBtn() {
   
    setCity("XXXX")
    
    
    const userInfo: LoginRequest = {
        uniqueId: 'XXXXX',
        phoneOs: 'XXXX',
        gender: 'X',
        phoneName: 'XXXX',
        lat: XXXX,
        lon: XXXX
    }
    await login(userInfo)
    getEventsInCity("XXXX").then((o) =>{
        
        setEvents([...o.data])
        
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    
}
```

My HTML (I am using a bottom sheet package)
The last EventCell is just for testing that my view is showing

```
<BottomSheetScrollView 
                horizontal={false}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                style={styles.eventScrollView}
                >
                                
                {events.map((e, i) => {
                    <EventCell event={e} onClick={(eventClicked)} />
                    
                })}
                <EventCell event={testEvent} onClick={(eventClicked)} />

                    </BottomSheetScrollView>
```

Comment: Your map doesn't return anything.

Comment: Oh my god..... Yes you are completly correct Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a comment from @windowsill I figured out the solution.

The .map function needs to have a return like this.

```
{events.map((e, i) => {
                    return <EventCell event={e} onClick={(eventClicked)} />
                })}
```

Comment: Remember to add a key prop to any list of components!

Answer (score 0):

Are you totally sure that `o.data` is an array? Can you log the `o` object and post here what get logged?